# Ubuntu Mate - Pi 3 - NFC 1.7.1

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, uart, mate, lib-nfc

I plug my pn532 NFC V3 in my Pi, I use this Scheme https://i.stack.imgur.com/deOfX.jpg

I'm using a Ubuntu Mate 16.04, I follow this steps:

Plug the board.
Change this file /boot/config.txt

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
enable_uart=1
```

Change /boot/cmdline.txt

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait quiet splash
```

Reboot all
Install NFC Tools - https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-nfc-rfid-on-raspberry-pi/building-libnfc

And, nothing works!

```
root@pi3:~# nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
No NFC device found.
```

Someone, can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Can you rephrase your question to have a specifically stated issue? Vague questions don't get answered on Stack Overflow, nor do general "Help me debug something you can't see" questions. Maybe try asking over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Jon, I try a lot of things. Serial, ttyAMA0. S0, change configs, changes uart anda nothing. I'm lost now. I tried to resume everything I do simplify the post. Sorry if I dont have more information, because, I dont have. I try, if this post, another opinion, perspective. Thanks anyway man.